# Is it possible to connect to a VPN from inside the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm developing a Wordpress site on a LAMP stack running inside of my WSL Ubuntu installation on Windows 10. There are certain REST calls that I need to make that require a VPN connection to the server. I have the VPN connection working properly on an actual Ubuntu server but when I run the exact same configuration inside WSL, it fails to connect. Is this even supported? I know there are limitations in WSL. I can't seem to find any clear information as most articles talk about Windows 10 itself (the host) connecting to the VPN.

Comment: Searching for the same problem I found out that this is a pending open issue on WSL Github [https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/416](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/416).

Comment: I don't know what my admin did.. but he had it working with OpenVPN (it initially did not work).  I think he messed with resolv.conf to get it to work.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I have successfully used openvpn to connect to an office VPN using WSL2 on Windows 10 and Windows 11

Answer (score 1):

At the time this question was asked, WSL2 had not yet been release.

- On WSL1, the answer is "no".  WSL1 uses the same networking interfaces as Windows, but it does not provide you with any *control* over those interfaces.  For this reason, you cannot directly connect to a VPN from *within* WSL.  You could connect to a VPN within Windows itself, and any processes running in WSL1 would utilize the Windows routing.
- For WSL2, the situation is almost reversed.  WSL2 uses a virtualized, NAT'd network behind a Hyper-V (based) switch.  You can connect to many (probably most) VPNs in a WSL2 distribution as long as you have the appropriate software running on the Linux-end.

  (While note part of the question) The downside to WSL2 regarding VPNs is that running a VPN on the *Windows* side will often turn off *all* network access from the virtualized WSL2 network, depending on the VPN settings.  Many corporate VPNs are designed to disable access to local networks (of which the WSL2 network is one) for security reasons.